# Python: How to multply a dictionary of lists for a dictionary of float numbers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I was wondering if it is possible to to multply a dictionary of lists of integers for a dictionary of float numbers. Both dictionary have the same keys.

I have a dictionary

```
q = dict(((i, f), somefloatnumber) for i in I for f in F)
p = dict(((i, f), somelistofinteger) for i in I for f in F)
```

For instance, if I have:

```
dict1={(0, 0):[1, 0, 1], (0, 1):[1, 0, 0], (0, 2):[0, 0, 1]}

dict2={(0, 0): 10.54, (0, 1): 47.32, (0, 2): 33.1}
```

The output would be:

```
dict3={(0, 0):[10.54, 0, 10.54], (0, 1):[47.32, 0, 0], (0, 2):[0, 0, 33.1]}
```

Is there a way to multiply the dictionary `q` and `p`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this `(0, 0): 10,54,` is invalid notation. Did you mean `(0, 0): [10,54],` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest based on OPs specified output, he/she most likely simply refers to a decimal number (floating point), but uses a locale with decimal commas rather than decimal points (which is not appropriate to use in python source code).

Comment: @dfri, it seems like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
dict1 = {(0, 0):[1, 0, 1], (0, 1):[1, 0, 0], (0, 2):[0, 0, 1]}
dict2 = {(0, 0): 10.54, (0, 1): 47.32, (0, 2): 33.1}
dict3 = {}

for key, elems in dict1.items():
    multiplier = dict2[key]
    dict3[key] = [multiplier*elem for elem in elems]

# dict3 = 
# {(0, 0): [10.54, 0.0, 10.54],
#  (0, 1): [47.32, 0.0, 0.0],
#  (0, 2): [0.0, 0.0, 33.1]}
```

I'm assuming by 10,54 you actually mean 10.54. In programming you have to represent decimals as a `.`

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Of course I meant 10.54, I will edit right now.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-requisite:

> *"Both dictionaries have the same keys."*

You could use dict comprehension wrapping a list comprehension for the list multiplications:

```
dict1 = {(0, 0): [1, 0, 1], (0, 1): [1, 0, 0], (0, 2): [0, 0, 1]}
dict2 = {(0, 0): 10.54,     (0, 1): 47.32,     (0, 2): 33.1}
dict3 = {k: [dict2[k]*x for x in v] for k, v in dict1.items()}
# dict3 = 
# {(0, 0): [10.54, 0.0, 10.54],
#  (0, 1): [47.32, 0.0, 0.0],
#  (0, 2): [0.0, 0.0, 33.1]}
```

Or, instead of the inner list comprehension, use `map` with a lambda:

```
dict1 = {(0, 0): [1, 0, 1], (0, 1): [1, 0, 0], (0, 2): [0, 0, 1]}
dict2 = {(0, 0): 10.54,     (0, 1): 47.32,     (0, 2): 33.1}
dict3 = {k: map(lambda x: dict2[k]*x, v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
# dict3 = 
# {(0, 0): [10.54, 0.0, 10.54],
#  (0, 1): [47.32, 0.0, 0.0],
#  (0, 2): [0.0, 0.0, 33.1]}
```

Comment: I also had thoughts about `map` one-liner, ++

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** I guess, you mean lists in dict 2. Please wrap them with `[` and `]`

**Edit 2:** You edited your question after my answer. For everyone who is looking for a solution where dict2 does not contain floats but lists of integers ( [10,54] instead of 10.54 ) here is my solution. Otherwise please read the accepted answer.

Of course there is a way to do that. You could simply cycle through each of the keys:

```
resultDict = {}  # = dict3
for key in dict1:
    multiplierList = dict2[key]
    sourceList = dict1[key]
    resultDict[key] = []
    for sourceElement in sourceList:
        if sourceElement == 0:        #in your question you described that in dict3 you would only have one 0 element.
            resultDict[key].append(0) #without these two lines you would have as many 0's as there are multipliers (in the example there would be two 0's)            
        for multiplier in multiplierList:
            resultDict[key].append(sourceElement * multiplier)
```

This code iterates over each of the list elements in dict1 and multiplies it with each of the elements in dict2 and appends them to the resultDict.

Comment: this doesnt produce the same result as OPs requirement

Comment: Why does it not produce the same?

Comment: Oh. Of course it isn't. It's because he updated his question.

Comment: OP wants `dict3={(0, 0): [10.54, 0, 10.54], (0, 1): [47.32, 0, 0], (0, 2): [0, 0, 33.1]}` your result (before the edit) doesnt produce did, did you change it?

Comment: Yeah. I changed it. I will change it again because I was assuming he wanted [10,54] instead of 10.54.